# ebean update() sometimes does not persist object

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, ebean

I have a play app (play v2.3.4 - with ebean) that will soon go into service. during my tests these days, I'm seeing something very strange! sometimes the update() method for persisting model in DB does not work (without any exception or so). I am looking for the problem, until now I have these 3 in mind:

1. I'm using `update()` and not `update(id)` , maybe this is the problem?
2. I'm using public fields without getter/setters, I have seen that this sometimes makes problems and i get `null` back, so I will change to private fields + getter/setters later. but for now , can this be the problem?
3. once that I found out that `update()`does not work properly for all objects, I did a `activator clean` and after that, things went well. (another time this cleaning didn't help)

for example in my code, I have a loop over some objects, inside my loop, I change a property of each of those objects, and call the `update()` for that object. for some of them, the changes get persisted, for some not!!! (this peace of code gets executed periodically via a AKKA scheduler in my `app/Global.java`)

```
for (User respPerson : event.setup.respPersons) {
   respPerson.addNotification(notification);
   respPerson.update();
}
```

UPDATE:
changing from `update()` to `update(id)` did not solve the problem. 
here is a picture of the debugger for 2 `User` instances. the one in the right updates always successfully , the left one not... 
[image]

**UPDATE2**
more info about the example above: 
inside loop, I add a notification to a User instance (User holds a `List` of notifications). now if I check the `User` instance with my debugger, it has a new `Notification` in it notification list. so everything should be fine... then i call `update()`, and expect that the changes should be persisted in DB. but after `update` when I use a Static call and get the `User` with the same `id` from DB, it does not contain the notification that I added before!

This always happens for a specific instance of Object(in the picture above, the user with the id 33). I tried to add a `Notification` to this `User` instance in another `controller`, and it got persisted. but every time I do this inside `Global.java` using a scheduled task, it does not get persisted.

**UPDATE! The problem is found and fixed. I will update this question in the next couple of hours.**

Comment: What ended up fixing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mix public properties and getters\setters ? Ebean (Play) autogenerate getters\setters if you do not create any of them in the Model otherwise you need to create all of them. You can switch off this feature but by default it's on.

Look at your code and try to recognize that you always use the same style.

For example, I see that you use `respPerson.addNotification(notification);` so you need to use something like `setId` as well:

```
respPerson.setId(1L); // will work 
respPerson.id = 1L;   // will not work
```

Comment: Some of my Models have getter/setters for all of their fields, some of Models have all public fields without any getter/setter. I'm not sure how play finds out if there exists any getter/setters but I assume they use Java reflections and for example search for "set"+fieldName.

I updated my question with more info. do you still think that setter/getters are problem?